# Datalist not showing options, if records more than 500

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

```js
function loadDynamicDatalist() {
  let d = document.getElementById("browsers");
  let options = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 1200; i++) {
    options += '<option value="datalist' + i + '">datalist' + i + '</option>';
  }
  d.innerHTML = options;
}
loadDynamicDatalist();
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
  <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">

        </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The datalist tag is not supported in Safari 12.0 (or earlier).</p>
```

Datalist is only showing records around 500 instead of 1200 records. Please suggest me a idea how to show all values in datalist.

Comment: It's terrible UX to have a list of 1200 records to scroll through to find the one they want to select. The point of using a `datalist` is so that they can type and see matches. For instance, if I want to see "datalist600" I can type "datalist6" and see "datalist6", "datalist60", etc., including "datalist600".

Comment: But the requirement in my case is the user wants to see the all options, but if needed only they can search. Anyways to do that?

Comment: Use something other than `datalist`. Like a `select` with an `input` for searching. There are many, many, autocomplete controls on the internet that can do this too.